# What does 'DispatchQueue.main.async' and 'completed: @escaping () -> ()' mean in this snippet of code?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, grand-central-dispatch

Basically this is a simple project that involves a tableview that is updated according to data that is parsed from JSON from an api. I believe `DispatchQueue.main.async` and `completed: @escaping () -> ()` have something to do with updating/reloading the tableview but I'm not sure how it works. Explanation would be appreciated on what these two do.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var heroes = [HeroStats]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData {
            print("Success")
        }
    }

    func fetchData(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {

        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            if error == nil {
                do {
                    let heroes = try JSONDecoder().decode([HeroStats].self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` means "run this following code inside the braces on the main queue" (which is where all UI updates must run). `URLSession` closures and delegate methods run on a dedicated `URLSession` queue, but UI (and model) updates should happen on the main queue.

   FYI, the two common methods of dispatching code to another queue are `async` and `sync`. They're very similar, but `async` runs asynchronously (i.e. the code after the `async` call won't wait for the main thread to finish calling `completed` before continuing), and `sync` runs synchronously (i.e. it would wait). In this case, there's no point in having the `URLSession` queue to wait for the main queue to finish, so `async` is appropriate.
2. The `completed: @escaping () -> ()` indicates that:

   - there is a parameter to `fetchData`, called `completed`;
   - that this parameter is a "closure" (i.e. an anonymous bit of code that the caller can provide; see [The Swift Programming Language: Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) for more information);
   - this closure that takes no parameters, itself, nor returns anything; and
   - this closure "escapes" (meaning that it won't necessarily be run by the time the `fetchData` method returns).

   So, you could pass a block of code to be called (when you see `completed()` in the `dataTask` closure) like so:

   ```
   fetchData(completed: {
       print("Success")
       self.tableView.reloadData()  // make sure to reload table when request is done
   })
   ```

   But, your example uses "trailing closure" syntax, where the final closure (and in this case, the only closure) can be omitted as a parameter, and just added after the `fetchData` call, resulting in the same behavior (but more concise syntax):

   ```
   fetchData {
       print("Success")
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
   ```

   Or, even better:

   ```
   fetchData { [weak self] in
       print("Success")
       self?.tableView.reloadData()
   }
   ```
3. In an unrelated observation, you never update your `heroes` property. At the very least, you should do:

   ```
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
       guard let data = data, error == nil else { 
           print(error ?? "Unknown error")
           return 
       }

       do {
           let heroes = try JSONDecoder().decode([HeroStats].self, from: data)
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.heroes = heroes
               completed()
           }
       } catch let error {
           print(error)
       }
   }.resume()
   ```

   Note, you want to update the `self.heroes` property *inside* the `async` closure to make sure that you don’t update the property from a background thread. Arrays are not thread-safe, and by updating that property on the main thread, you avoid any race conditions.

   There are many other improvements I could suggest (use `weak` reference to `self` in `dataTask`; add a parameter to your `completed` closure so the caller knows if it was successful and display warning if it wasn’t, etc.), but the above is the bare minimum that I’d suggest.

Comment: My question had a typo I actually meant to say "async" rather than "sync". I just edited the original question to fix it. Nonetheless, I really appreciate your thorough response. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. The property `heroes` is not the same object as the local variable `heroes` in the `do` block. You have to replace the `let` keyword with `self`

   ```
   self.heroes = try JSONDecoder().decode([HeroStats].self, from: data)
   ```

   and as `dataTask` can create a retain cycle add `[unowned self]` to avoid that:

   ```
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [unowned self] (data, response, error) in ...
   ```
2. In the completion block you have to reload the table view.

   ```
   fetchData() {
       print("Success")
       tableView.reloadData()
   }
   ```

The syntax `DispatchQueue.main.async` is correct. `sync` would block the thread.

Note: You can delete the check `if error == nil`. If the `guard` succeeds `error` is guaranteed to be `nil.` It's better to check the error rather than `data`

```
if let error = error { 
   print(error)
   return 
}

 do {
    self.heroes = try JSONDecoder().decode([HeroStats].self, from: data!)
    ...
```

Comment: You really don't want to use `[unowned self]` in asynchronous closure like `dataTask`. First, he doesn't reference `self` anywhere in there so it's unnecessary. And, second, if he did, and the view controller was dismissed, his code would crash. If (a) the closure did reference `self`; and (b) you didn't want the view controller retained while the asynchronous request was being processed, you should use `[weak self]`, not `[unowned self]`.

Comment: I disagree. In this case (actually in almost all cases) the view controller is  not being dismissed so `[unowned self]` is absolutely safe. I'm using it in **all** my projects and had never a problem. And `dataTask` won't release the completion closure without `unowned / weak self`

Comment: OK, we'll agree to disagree. The `dataTask` is running asynchronously and you have zero assurances that the view controller wasn't dismissed in the intervening time. What if you're on slow network connection and the user hits "Back" button on navigation bar (or whatever) because they're tired of waiting? It's extremely imprudent to ever use `unowned` when dealing with escaping closures that might be called asynchronously at a later point in time. Sure, 99.9% of the time you'll be fine, but you can easily crash app if user happens to dismiss view controller before the network request finishes.