# Pulling JSON data with a 3rd party library swift 4

Tags: json, swift, cocoapods

I am using a 3rd party GitHub library in my Xcode folder. Its giving me access to Yelps API where i would like to get search results within my app. I am successfully downloading converting the data into a JSON string.

But i'm stuck on the logic of Decoding the JSON string so that i can access the actual parameters, such as name, display_address and price. I have use "Decode" before, but never through a 3rd party library. I'm sure its possible and i'm probably just a step or two steps away, but my inexperience is impeding that right now. Any help. Thank you

Here is my function to get the JSON data and below is the response i get

```
func getYelp() {
    let yelpAPIClient = CDYelpAPIClient(apiKey: "MY_API_KEY")

    yelpAPIClient.cancelAllPendingAPIRequests()
    CDYelpFusionKitManager.shared.apiClient = yelpAPIClient

    CDYelpFusionKitManager.shared.apiClient.searchBusinesses(byTerm: "Bars", 
        location: "Hollywood, California", 
        latitude: nil, 
        longitude: nil, 
        radius: 10000, 
        categories: [CDYelpBusinessCategoryFilter.bars],
        locale: CDYelpLocale.english_unitedStates, 
        limit: 5, 
        offset: 0, 
        sortBy: CDYelpBusinessSortType.distance, 
        priceTiers: [CDYelpPriceTier.twoDollarSigns],
        openNow: true, 
        openAt: nil, 
        attributes: nil) { (response) in

        if let response = response,
            let businesses = response.businesses?.toJSONString(),
            businesses.count > 0 {
            print(businesses)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the data:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "The Know Where Bar",
    "coordinates" : {
      "latitude" : 34.101480000000002,
      "longitude" : -118.3127424
    },
    "rating" : 4.5,
    "price" : "$$",
    "review_count" : 170,
    "display_phone" : "(323) 871-4108",
    "location" : {
      "state" : "CA",
      "address3" : "",
      "address1" : "5634 Hollywood Blvd",
      "city" : "Los Angeles",
      "display_address" : [
        "5634 Hollywood Blvd",
        "Los Angeles, CA 90028"
      ],
      "zip_code" : "90028",
      "country" : "US"
    },
    "id" : "KOj4TvBuvRLXlBuG2vrZeQ",
    "categories" : [
      {
        "title" : "Cocktail Bars",
        "alias" : "cocktailbars"
      },
      {
        "title" : "Jazz & Blues",
        "alias" : "jazzandblues"
      },
      {
        "title" : "Pubs",
        "alias" : "pubs"
      }
    ],
    "transactions" : [

    ],
    "distance" : 2232.7094070718849,
    "phone" : "+13238714108",
    "image_url" : "https:\/\/s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com\/bphoto\/Ehus0C-bAoA-6fNbwGpSYA\/o.jpg",
    "is_closed" : false,
    "url" : "https:\/\/www.yelp.com\/biz\/the-know-where-bar-los-angeles?adjust_creative=xVfmfDi4k3F3Jm9zaJU1CA&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=xVfmfDi4k3F3Jm9zaJU1CA"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Lost Property Bar",
    "coordinates" : {
      "latitude" : 34.1019182,
      "longitude" : -118.32650390000001
    },
    "rating" : 4.5,
    "price" : "$$",
    "review_count" : 143,
    "display_phone" : "(323) 987-4445",
    "location" : {
      "state" : "CA",
      "address3" : "",
      "address1" : "1704 N Vine St",
      "city" : "Hollywood",
      "address2" : "",
      "display_address" : [
        "1704 N Vine St",
        "Hollywood, CA 90028"
      ],
      "zip_code" : "90028",
      "country" : "US"
    },
    "id" : "CBYwPYYEFbpCefJ4rdiyPw",
    "categories" : [
      {
        "title" : "Pubs",
        "alias" : "pubs"
      },
      {
        "title" : "Cocktail Bars",
        "alias" : "cocktailbars"
      }
    ],
    "transactions" : [

    ],
    "distance" : 1145.5564586880064,
    "phone" : "+13239874445",
    "image_url" : "https:\/\/s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com\/bphoto\/pswDPAX_3p73JbPEXwThag\/o.jpg",
    "is_closed" : false,
    "url" : "https:\/\/www.yelp.com\/biz\/lost-property-bar-hollywood?adjust_creative=xVfmfDi4k3F3Jm9zaJU1CA&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=xVfmfDi4k3F3Jm9zaJU1CA"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Sunset & Vinyl",
    "coordinates" : {
      "latitude" : 34.098346200000002,
      "longitude" : -118.32679779999999
    },
    "rating" : 4.5,
    "price" : "$$",
    "review_count" : 42,
    "display_phone" : "(424) 646-3375",
    "location" : {
      "state" : "CA",
      "city" : "Los Angeles",
      "address1" : "1521 Vine St",
      "address2" : "",
      "display_address" : [
        "1521 Vine St",
        "Los Angeles, CA 90028"
      ],
      "zip_code" : "90028",
      "country" : "US"
    },
    "id" : "RKSPAI90ITxbnq1-L_F5NA",
    "categories" : [
      {
        "title" : "Cocktail Bars",
        "alias" : "cocktailbars"
      },
      {
        "title" : "Speakeasies",
        "alias" : "speakeasies"
      },
      {
        "title" : "Lounges",
        "alias" : "lounges"
      }
    ],
    "transactions" : [

    ],
    "distance" : 916.67964443671087,
    "phone" : "+14246463375",
    "image_url" : "https:\/\/s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com\/bphoto\/w91DLpKmUGuXTF-zauYAWA\/o.jpg",
    "is_closed" : false,
    "url" : "https:\/\/www.yelp.com\/biz\/sunset-and-vinyl-los-angeles?adjust_creative=xVfmfDi4k3F3Jm9zaJU1CA&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=xVfmfDi4k3F3Jm9zaJU1CA"
  },
  {
    "name" : "A Simple Bar",
    "coordinates" : {
      "latitude" : 34.129899999999999,
      "longitude" : -118.34882
    },
    "rating" : 5,
    "price" : "$$",
    "review_count" : 168,
    "display_phone" : "(323) 378-5388",
    "location" : {
      "state" : "CA",
      "address3" : "",
      "address1" : "3256 Cahuenga Blvd W",
      "city" : "Los Angeles",
      "display_address" : [
        "3256 Cahuenga Blvd W",
        "Los Angeles, CA 90068"
      ],
      "zip_code" : "90068",
      "country" : "US"
    },
    "id" : "qD3-5yqSyPiz-VpJtPsnkg",
    "categories" : [
      {
        "title" : "Bars",
        "alias" : "bars"
      }
    ],
    "transactions" : [

    ],
    "distance" : 4136.336282884502,
    "phone" : "+13233785388",
    "image_url" : "https:\/\/s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com\/bphoto\/JYcRYDteiyjLh3dSAj7fCg\/o.jpg",
    "is_closed" : false,
    "url" : "https:\/\/www.yelp.com\/biz\/a-simple-bar-los-angeles?adjust_creative=xVfmfDi4k3F3Jm9zaJU1CA&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=xVfmfDi4k3F3Jm9zaJU1CA"
  },
  {
    "name" : "The Woods",
    "coordinates" : {
      "latitude" : 34.098860000000002,
      "longitude" : -118.34478
    },
    "rating" : 4,
    "price" : "$$",
    "review_count" : 456,
    "display_phone" : "(323) 876-6612",
    "location" : {
      "state" : "CA",
      "address3" : "",
      "address1" : "1533 N La Brea Ave",
      "city" : "Hollywood",
      "address2" : "",
      "display_address" : [
        "1533 N La Brea Ave",
        "Hollywood, CA 90028"
      ],
      "zip_code" : "90028",
      "country" : "US"
    },
    "id" : "UEim6Xi_sm78yDUpSfI-OQ",
    "categories" : [
      {
        "title" : "Lounges",
        "alias" : "lounges"
      }
    ],
    "transactions" : [

    ],
    "distance" : 968.92997694605617,
    "phone" : "+13238766612",
    "image_url" : "https:\/\/s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com\/bphoto\/wUQYIlojm2d41ZL38zDMgg\/o.jpg",
    "is_closed" : false,
    "url" : "https:\/\/www.yelp.com\/biz\/the-woods-hollywood?adjust_creative=xVfmfDi4k3F3Jm9zaJU1CA&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=xVfmfDi4k3F3Jm9zaJU1CA"
  }
]
```

Comment: What's your issue with `Decode` for this JSON? What have you got so far? I suggest to remove the `getYelp()` code as it seems unrelated to your your question. Possibly also just show that section of JSON that gives you trouble.

Comment: Would i go about decoding this normally? Like making structures to match the response ? I am confused because when ive normally decoded JSON, it was after doing a URLSession, but with this, since its from a 3rd party, its a bit different. So basically- i would decode this as if it were any other URL response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd party library already does all the decoding for you. Don't convert the response back to a JSON string.

`response.businesses` is an array of `CDYelpBusiness` objects, which are defined like this:

```
public var id: String?
public var name: String?
public var imageUrl: URL?
public var isClosed: Bool?
public var url: URL?
public var price: String?
public var phone: String?
public var displayPhone: String?
public var photos: [String]?
public var hours: [CDYelpHour]?
public var rating: Double?
public var reviewCount: Int?
public var categories: [CDYelpCategory]?
public var distance: Double?
public var coordinates: CDYelpCoordinates?
public var location: CDYelpLocation?
public var transactions: [String]?
```

Try iterating over them and accessing their properties like this:

```
for business in response.businesses {
    print(business.name)
}
```

Comment: Mike! That was exactly what i was looking for!! I was confused and my understanding was a little bit backwards. But you cleared it up perfectly. Thank you for taking the time

Comment: Hey Mike, is there a specific reason why i can only access these objects within the iteration loop? For instance, i am trying to store some of these properties within a table view, but i cannot access that "business" variable anywhere outside of this function. Thanks

Comment: The reason is that `businesses` is defined and accessible only within the closure of the `searchBusinesses` call, which is undoubtedly happening on a different thread than the main thread. To get the data out of the closure, you might assign `businesses` to a class-level var within your table view controller. This situation is not unique to this 3rd party library but is a common scenario when handling the response from network calls.

Comment: Mike; thank you again for the advice. I assigned businesses to a class level var- but unfortunately I still have trouble accessing that variable for some reason.. for example- I made arrayBusiness = [businesses] but when I use a print statement to show the contents of the that array. It just prints as [] .. I thought maybe I shouldn’t make it an array, but I feel like that is the best way to go about it, since I’ll be getting multiple values back.. any ideas?

Comment: Actually, my advice on assigning businesses was not correct. Try doing it within a DispatchQueue.main.async block, as described in point 3 of Rob's answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699048/what-does-dispatchqueue-main-async-and-completed-escaping-mean-in